# App widgets removed in home launcher if manifest activity intent-filter changed to different activity

Tags: android, android-activity, widget, android-manifest, splash-screen

I have an app with widgets. I created a new activity for a splash screen to show for a second and declared the new activity in my manifest with the intent-filter tags. I changed this:

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

to this:

```
<activity
  android:name=".SplashScreen"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

When I launched my app to the emulator, my widgets disappear from the home launcher and I have to re-add them. I want to add a splash screen to my app but I don't want my users to have to re-add their widgets, if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: "I want to add a splash screen to my app" -- why do you think your users want to waste their time with your splash screen? I have yet to find a single designer who thinks that splash screens are a good idea in any circumstances. Also, chaining the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activity in an app is going to cause other problems, as not all home screens will necessarily immediately detect this change, preventing the user from running your app. While I cannot see how the change you made would affect your app widgets, I strongly discourage the change in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm adding some server-end updates to be pushed to my app and wanted to do it there rather than a progress bar on startup. I thought it would look nicer. It's only text so the splash screen would show more than a second. But I'll use your comments to help my design decision. What problems would come from chaining main launcher. What is the proper way to do it?